# Show hidden columns in Kendo grid excel export

Tags: excel, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I have a kendo grid and I can export its data into excel file without any problem. In my grid, some columns may be hidden because they do not have any value. However, I want even these hidden columns (I mean their header) be in my exported excel file.

Here is a piece of code showing the excel config in my Kendo grid configuration.

```
excel: {
         fileName: new Date().toString() + ".xlsx",
         allPages: true,
       },
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can have columns in an array which defines hidden: true and then simply traverse through columns array and show/hide columns just before export as following:

```
        function excelExport(e) {
              if (!exportFlag) {
                  for(var i=0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                      if(columns[i].hidden)
                          e.sender.showColumn(i);
                  }
                  e.preventDefault();
                  exportFlag = true;
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    e.sender.saveAsExcel();
                  });
                } else {
                    for(var i=0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                          if(columns[i].hidden)
                              e.sender.hideColumn(i);
                      }
                  exportFlag = false;
                }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some javascript to control this.

```
var exportFlag = true;

$("#gridName").data("kendoGrid").bind("excelExport", function (e) {
    if (exportFlag) {
        e.sender.showColumn("hiddenColumnName");
        e.preventDefault();
        exportFlag = false;
        e.sender.saveAsExcel();
    } else {
        e.sender.hideColumn("hiddenColumnName");
        exportFlag = true;
    }
});
```

Basically this catches the `excelExport` event when you click the Export button and shows the hidden column in your grid before it fires the `saveAsExcel()` function which saves your document. Then it hides the column again.

Here is an [Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/obUYa/81) you can test with.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The first point is that I want the hidden columns be recognized automatically (not manually by putting their name!). P.S. the example that you have provided does not seem to be correct!

Comment: Ok so basically we need a way to loop through each column and see if the `hidden` property is `true` or `false`. I'll do some research to see if I can figure this out. What is wrong with the example? There are 3 columns in the grid and the 3rd column is hidden. When you click the Export button it shows the hidden column in the excel document.

Comment: The example did not work because Telerik is not supported in Iran! (any reference directly from its website). I had to use a proxy in order to see the excel export result and now it is working. However, the first problem still exists. I want even hidden columns be automatically in my excel file.

Comment: I don't really know what the other commenters meant, the example worked perfectly for me and was the most correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to achieve a similar thing and used the answer provided by @Ankur with slight modification as I needed to hide the columns again after the export.

Code as follows:

```
excelExport(e) {
                Spa.startLoading(); // loading overlay to hide the columns showing then hiding again
                var columns = e.sender.columns;
                var hiddenColumnNumbers = [];
                if (!exportFlag) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                        if (columns[i].hidden) {
                            e.sender.showColumn(i);
                            hiddenColumnNumbers.push(i);
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                    exportFlag = true;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        e.sender.saveAsExcel();
                        for (let j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
                            if (hiddenColumnNumbers.indexOf(j) > -1) {
                                e.sender.hideColumn(j);
                            }
                        }
                        Spa.stopLoading(); // hide loading overlay
                    });
                } else {
                    for (let k = 0; k < columns.length; k++) {
                        if (columns[k].hidden)
                            e.sender.hideColumn(k);
                    }
                    exportFlag = false;
                    Spa.stopLoading(); // hide loading overlay
                }
            },
```