# Here , is my kendo grid, i want to show vendorNo field at the time of excel export but not on grid

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a kendo grid, the problem is that at the time of Excel export all fields are shown which is bound but I want to add one more field not on the grid but on Excel sheet...

eg; I want to show VendorNo field on excel sheet, not on kendo grid. How can I get the values to show up in the excel export?

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CrystalPower.Web.ViewModels.RechargeLogViewModel>().Name("RechargeReport").Columns(c =>
                                {
                                    c.Bound(x => x.CreatedDate).Title("Created<br/>On").Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
                                    c.Bound(x => x.MeterNo).Title("Meter No.").Filterable(f => f.Extra(true)
                                                                .Operators(o => o.ForString(s => s.Clear()
                                                                .Contains("Contains")
                                                                .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
                                                                .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                                                                .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                                                                .StartsWith("Starts with")
                                                                .EndsWith("Ends with ")
                                                                )));
                                    c.Bound(x => x.UnitName).Title(unitType);
                                    c.Bound(x => x.CustomerPhone).Title("Customer<br/>Phone");
                                    c.Bound(x => x.CustomerName).Title("Customer<br/>Name").ClientFooterTemplate("Total: ");
                                    c.Bound(x => x.Amount).ClientTemplate("#=Amount#").Title("Amount").ClientFooterTemplate("#=sum#"); ;
                                    c.Bound(x => x.RechargeLogTypeId).Title("Type").ClientTemplate("#=crystalPower.getRechargeLogType(RechargeLogTypeId) #");
                                    c.Bound(x => x.PaymentModeId).Title("Payment Mode").ClientTemplate("#=crystalPower.getPaymentMode(PaymentModeId) #");
                                    c.Bound(x => x.RefrenceNo).Title("Ref. No");
                                    c.Bound(x => x.BankName).Title("Bank Name");
                                    c.Bound(x => x.PaymentDetail).Title("Card/Cheque Detail");
                                    c.Bound(x => x.Remarks).Title("Remarks");
                                    c.Template(m => @Html.ActionLink("", "", "", new { guid = m.Guid }, null))
                                           .Width(75)
                                           .ClientTemplate("<div class='btn-group'>" +
                                                            "<a target='_blank' href='" + Url.Content("~/Recharge/AcknowledgementSlip?guid=#=Guid#") + "' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-print'></i> Print</a>" +
                                                            "</div>");
                                }).DataSource(d => d.Ajax().PageSize(30)
                                                  .Read(r => r.Action("GetRechargeRecordDetail", "Report", new { fromDate = @Model.FromDate, toDate = @Model.ToDate }))
                                                  .Aggregates(aggregates =>
                                                  {
                                                      aggregates.Add(p => p.Amount).Sum();
                                                  })
                                            ).AutoBind(true)
             .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] { 30, 60, 100 }))

             .Sortable().Resizable(c => c.Columns(true))
             .Events(e => e.ExcelExport("excelExport"))
             .Reorderable(c => c.Columns(true))
             .Filterable()
              .ToolBar(x => x.Template
                           (@<text>
                <div class="dropdown pull-right">
                    <button class="k-button" id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Export
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                        <li>
                            <a class="k-grid-excel">Excel</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="k-grid-pdf">PDF</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                        </text>
                                        )
        )
        .Excel(excel => excel.FileName("Recharge Report.xlsx")
                            .Filterable(true)
                            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ToExcelOrPdf", "Report"))
                     .AllPages(true)

            )
                    .Pdf(pdf => pdf.AllPages().FileName("Recharge Report.pdf")
                        .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ToExcelOrPdf", "Report"))


        )

// function for excel export
function excelExport(e) {
            debugger
            var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
            //var rechargeLogTemplate = kendo.template(this.columns[6].template);
            //var paymentModeTemplate = kendo.template(this.columns[7].template);

          //  var data = this.dataSource.view();

            for (var i = 0; i < sheet.rows.length-1; i++) {
                sheet.rows[i + 1].cells[6].value = crystalPower.getRechargeLogType(sheet.rows[i + 1].cells[6].value).replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
                sheet.rows[i + 1].cells[7].value = crystalPower.getPaymentModeType(sheet.rows[i + 1].cells[7].value).replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you format your code and tell us what exactly is not working with this mess and what you've tried to spot the error?

Comment: @– Nico Haase, there is one more field on my database vendor I want to show this field on Excel sheet at the time of Excel Export, not on kendo grid.

Comment: 1. https://www.telerik.com/forums/export-to-grid-hide-columns

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420374/show-hidden-columns-in-kendo-grid-excel-export

Check these

Comment: @ Arijit Mukherjee, thanx that's solve my problem